# Web scraping for Google Ads using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape for  Google search results that have the "Ad" in the right, ie scraping for Google ad links from search results.
I have the following script, where I am stuck at soup.select() step. I am not sure which selectors to use... Any help is appreciated in advance
inspect element below:
[screen capture of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xGIB.png)

```html
#! python3
#!usr/bin/env python3

import  requests, bs4, webbrowser

#Get Google search results
ui_search = input("Search google: ")
print('Googling...') #display text while downloading
if len(ui_search)>1:
    res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(ui_search))
    res.raise_for_status()

#Retrieve the results with ads and open them.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

#Open a browser tab for each result
linkElems = soup.select('.V0MxL a')
linkElems2 = soup.select('.ad_cclk a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
print(numOpen)
for i in range(numOpen):
    print(linkElems[i].get('href'))
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' +linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Code for similar code without specifying for ads:

```html
#! python3
#lucky.py - Opens several Google search results.

import requests
import sys
import webbrowser
import bs4

ui_search = input("Search google: ")
print('Googling...') #display text while downloading
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
elif len(ui_search) > 1:
    res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(ui_search))
    res.raise_for_status()

#Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
#type(soup)
#Open a browser tab for each result
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    print(linkElems[i])
   # webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

```
Example results:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH3XF.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  And please...no screenshots.

Comment: please provide some example links with expected return values and as above: please do not post images of code. Use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html we can use for testing.

Comment: @QHarr, Thanks for the tip. I used the <code> parameter, cannot seem to find "snippet tool". Expected results are the first 5 or less links with ads in any google search. I will add an example of code showing links of all first 5 searches with and without ads.

Comment: @QHarr found the snippet tool, but no specification for python?

Comment: snippet tool if for adding html/js. To insert your python code paste the python into the question, select all that python code and press Ctrl + K (It indents all the code by 4 spaces which then puts it between code tags).

Comment: Even with googling, I'm not certain I know what a stack trace is. But the stack is python3 via pycharm.  linkElems = soup.select('.ad_cclk a') is the problematic line

Comment: what is the error message print out which indicates the error line and message?

Comment: There is no error message. Process just runs and finishes without doing anything. But I know the troublesome line is: linkElems = soup.select('.V0Mxl a'), because it is the line I changed in the second code

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, I would rather use `findAll()`/`find_all()` methods instead because this way I can get more specific and tell `bs4` to choose a  `tag` that contains specific `class` inside where I can grab ADs link URL's.

This will work only if Google shows those Ads while the script is running.

Code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/KnobbyPricklyEnvironments#main.py):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=graphic+card+buy&oq=graphic+card+buy&hl=en&gl=us&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8', headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for link in soup.findAll('div', class_='RnJeZd top pla-unit-title'):
  ad_link = link.a['href']
  print(f'https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead{ad_link}')
```

Output:

```
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwils83_1PrvAhUNjsgKHdWRC7sYABAFGgJxdQ&sig=AOD64_39ASmacGcHYwy9gGKmKFRuPLiOQg&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwinrcf_1PrvAhWFKs0KHZzNCsMQww96BAgCED0&adurl=
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwils83_1PrvAhUNjsgKHdWRC7sYABADGgJxdQ&sig=AOD64_2rqOA3PxFKKsigRh1yy3z5QKbtcw&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwinrcf_1PrvAhWFKs0KHZzNCsMQww96BAgCEEk&adurl=
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwils83_1PrvAhUNjsgKHdWRC7sYABAEGgJxdQ&sig=AOD64_0WuY3UDlgTziPk9nUw0f8s3zW3nA&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwinrcf_1PrvAhWFKs0KHZzNCsMQww96BAgCEFU&adurl=
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Ad Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-ads) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=booking%20hotel&gl=us&hl=en) to play around.

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "graphic card buy",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for ads in results["shopping_results"]:
   print(f"Ad link: {ads['link']}")
```

Part of JSON output:

```json
"shopping_results": [
  {
    "position": 1,
    "block_position": "top",
    "title": "MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti DirectX 12 GTX 1050 Ti GAMING X 4G 4GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready ATX Video Card",
    "price": "$378.96",
    "extracted_price": 378.96,
    "link": "https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwiSrfjp0_rvAhUPwMgKHSkHDA8YABAFGgJxdQ&sig=AOD64_0JBh0DChYqoc9ZOWb2n74I16DHbQ&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjFuvDp0_rvAhVLX60KHS1kB9sQ5bgDegQIARA9&adurl=",
    "source": "Newegg.com",
    "rating": 4.7,
    "reviews": 1000,
    "thumbnail": "https://serpapi.com/searches/60754272d036a77fb9aba998/images/948de68641995317c7afd6bdf3a72f7a9d55cad671345a21921df988b8b9ef6c.png"
  }
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.